# How do I use the "live" feature of bootstrap's popovers?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

In the old days, bootstrap's popover had a "live" option which allowed us to make the `$('.myclass').popover({live: true})` call even before the DOM elements existed. I looked at the docs for 2.2 and this seems to be gone. What's the new way to do it?

Answer (score 10):

The live mode is not used any more.

The Bootstrap JS plugins now use delegated events via the jQuery [.on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You can supply an event delegation target selector pointing to an element which might or might not exist.

```
$('.some-container').popover({
  selector: '.has-popover'
});
```

Working example generating DOM elements with popover attached: http://jsfiddle.net/asKF9/

Comment: How would you do a close?